# Cannot import matplotlib.pyplot 'Nonetype' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

I am just trying to import matplotlib.pyplot using Anaconda's latest version on Windows, importing matplotlib worked just fine, but when I try to import matplotlib.pyplot the following error is displayed:

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-a0d2faabd9e9>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 18, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1363, in <module>
    _rebuild()

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1344, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 978, in __init__
    ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()

  File "C:\Users\AbanoubMamdouh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 264, in findSystemFonts
    fontfiles.update(win32InstalledFonts(fontext=fontext))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

---

I looked up on similar errors on matplotlib.pyplot but none of them was 'NoneType' object.
Update: same error appeared when I tried to run the command:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

Anybody has any idea on how to fix this?

Cheers!

Comment: Looks like `win32InstalledFonts(fontext=fontext)` is returning `None`. So the question is why it's not returning the font list.

Comment: How can I know the reason that it's returning None? Any steps to perform?

Comment: See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12173 https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12174 https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12213 Those bugs appeared in matplotlib 3.0.0 There are possible workarounds mentionned, or you can use matplotlbi 2.2.3 until it'll be fixed in 3.0.1.